# Unable to host simple HelloWorld application in CF or access via local host

Tags: s4sdk, sap-cloud-sdk

I am following the course "S/4HANA Cloud SDK :Create and Deliver Cloud-Native SAP S/4HANA Extensions"

Build and install of project worked as expected.
But while trying to do `mvn tomee:run` application doesn't open in localhost.
Neither able to host the application in CF account, it runs into error while starting.

Attached the log from CF.

```
2019-03-27T11:25:48.952+0000 [API/6] OUT Created app with guid b07d82eb-c0a9-4778-97a3-0027cb123871

2019-03-27T11:25:54.116+0000 [API/28] OUT Updated app with guid b07d82eb-c0a9-4778-97a3-0027cb123871 ({"route"=>"e986a5a5-d86c-4fbe-a866-f388a4c33b5f", :verb=>"add", :relation=>"routes", :related_guid=>"e986a5a5-d86c-4fbe-a866-f388a4c33b5f"})

2019-03-27T11:25:59.566+0000 [API/11] OUT Uploading bits for app with guid b07d82eb-c0a9-4778-97a3-0027cb123871

2019-03-27T11:26:08.930+0000 [API/19] OUT Creating build for app with guid b07d82eb-c0a9-4778-97a3-0027cb123871

2019-03-27T11:26:09.191+0000 [API/19] OUT Updated app with guid b07d82eb-c0a9-4778-97a3-0027cb123871 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})

2019-03-27T11:26:09.504+0000 [STG/0] OUT Downloading sap_java_buildpack...

2019-03-27T11:26:09.534+0000 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded sap_java_buildpack

2019-03-27T11:26:09.535+0000 [STG/0] OUT Cell a1379abe-e72b-472c-a795-54efe92805e0 creating container for instance 810291d7-8da8-4265-b3d1-b59432076711

2019-03-27T11:26:10.084+0000 [STG/0] OUT Cell a1379abe-e72b-472c-a795-54efe92805e0 successfully created container for instance 810291d7-8da8-4265-b3d1-b59432076711

2019-03-27T11:26:10.280+0000 [STG/0] OUT Downloading app package...

2019-03-27T11:26:10.983+0000 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded app package (19.9M)

2019-03-27T11:26:11.036+0000 [STG/0] OUT Compiling Java application...

2019-03-27T11:26:12.795+0000 [STG/0] OUT Java XS Buildpack Version: 1.8.6

2019-03-27T11:26:12.810+0000 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded 'TomEE Runtime', version '1.7.5-jaxrs' in 0.2 s.

2019-03-27T11:26:13.236+0000 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded 'XS Authenticator', version '1.8.4' in 0.0 s.

2019-03-27T11:26:13.239+0000 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded 'SAPJWT', version '1.1.20' in 0.0 s.

2019-03-27T11:26:13.245+0000 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded 'SAPJVM Statistics Provider', version '1.8.8' in 0.0 s.

2019-03-27T11:26:13.250+0000 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded 'SAP JVM Memory Calculator', version '1.8.8' in 0.0 s.

2019-03-27T11:26:13.317+0000 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded 'XS Hystrix Plugin Hook', version '1.8.8' in 0.1 s.

2019-03-27T11:26:13.329+0000 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded 'JVMKill', version '1.12.0.RELEASE' in 0.0 s.

2019-03-27T11:26:21.716+0000 [STG/0] OUT Exit status 0

2019-03-27T11:26:21.716+0000 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...

2019-03-27T11:26:21.716+0000 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet...

2019-03-27T11:26:21.716+0000 [STG/0] OUT Uploading build artifacts cache...

2019-03-27T11:26:21.752+0000 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded build artifacts cache (132B)

2019-03-27T11:26:23.772+0000 [API/9] OUT Creating droplet for app with guid b07d82eb-c0a9-4778-97a3-0027cb123871

2019-03-27T11:26:32.113+0000 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded droplet (130.1M)

2019-03-27T11:26:32.279+0000 [STG/0] OUT Uploading complete

2019-03-27T11:26:32.653+0000 [STG/0] OUT Cell a1379abe-e72b-472c-a795-54efe92805e0 stopping instance 810291d7-8da8-4265-b3d1-b59432076711

2019-03-27T11:26:32.653+0000 [STG/0] OUT Cell a1379abe-e72b-472c-a795-54efe92805e0 destroying container for instance 810291d7-8da8-4265-b3d1-b59432076711

2019-03-27T11:26:33.440+0000 [STG/0] OUT Cell a1379abe-e72b-472c-a795-54efe92805e0 successfully destroyed container for instance 810291d7-8da8-4265-b3d1-b59432076711

2019-03-27T11:26:34.068+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 35f8dc07-edbb-496b-8286-58d05d7d2e2e creating container for instance 0e9c9ab9-7f0e-4ff3-4291-a01f

2019-03-27T11:26:34.559+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 35f8dc07-edbb-496b-8286-58d05d7d2e2e successfully created container for instance 0e9c9ab9-7f0e-4ff3-4291-a01f

2019-03-27T11:26:38.628+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container

2019-03-27T11:26:38.705+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR bash: S/4HANA: No such file or directory

2019-03-27T11:26:38.715+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 127

2019-03-27T11:26:39.015+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 35f8dc07-edbb-496b-8286-58d05d7d2e2e stopping instance 0e9c9ab9-7f0e-4ff3-4291-a01f

2019-03-27T11:26:39.015+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 35f8dc07-edbb-496b-8286-58d05d7d2e2e destroying container for instance 0e9c9ab9-7f0e-4ff3-4291-a01f

2019-03-27T11:26:39.081+0000 [API/17] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"

2019-03-27T11:26:39.103+0000 [API/17] OUT App instance exited with guid b07d82eb-c0a9-4778-97a3-0027cb123871 payload: {"instance"=>"0e9c9ab9-7f0e-4ff3-4291-a01f", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"35f8dc07-edbb-496b-8286-58d05d7d2e2e", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 127", "crash_count"=>1, "crash_timestamp"=>1553685998989822967, "version"=>"ce5d1861-170d-4eb6-a3b9-02738dea412f"}

2019-03-27T11:26:39.321+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 145bc1b7-519c-4329-a748-f81bb6e4322b creating container for instance 30138f08-341f-497f-7f2d-0861

2019-03-27T11:26:39.712+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 35f8dc07-edbb-496b-8286-58d05d7d2e2e successfully destroyed container for instance 0e9c9ab9-7f0e-4ff3-4291-a01f

2019-03-27T11:26:39.849+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 145bc1b7-519c-4329-a748-f81bb6e4322b successfully created container for instance 30138f08-341f-497f-7f2d-0861

2019-03-27T11:26:43.763+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container

2019-03-27T11:26:43.833+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR bash: S/4HANA: No such file or directory

2019-03-27T11:26:43.844+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 127

2019-03-27T11:26:44.200+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 145bc1b7-519c-4329-a748-f81bb6e4322b stopping instance 30138f08-341f-497f-7f2d-0861

2019-03-27T11:26:44.200+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 145bc1b7-519c-4329-a748-f81bb6e4322b destroying container for instance 30138f08-341f-497f-7f2d-0861

2019-03-27T11:26:44.211+0000 [API/16] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"

2019-03-27T11:26:44.220+0000 [API/16] OUT App instance exited with guid b07d82eb-c0a9-4778-97a3-0027cb123871 payload: {"instance"=>"30138f08-341f-497f-7f2d-0861", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"145bc1b7-519c-4329-a748-f81bb6e4322b", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 127", "crash_count"=>2, "crash_timestamp"=>1553686004169760016, "version"=>"ce5d1861-170d-4eb6-a3b9-02738dea412f"}

2019-03-27T11:26:44.531+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell dcee36cd-b198-4815-bc83-659c0ff008fd creating container for instance 54cb5da2-e6be-4c9f-5584-04b0

2019-03-27T11:26:44.886+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 145bc1b7-519c-4329-a748-f81bb6e4322b successfully destroyed container for instance 30138f08-341f-497f-7f2d-0861

2019-03-27T11:26:45.081+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell dcee36cd-b198-4815-bc83-659c0ff008fd successfully created container for instance 54cb5da2-e6be-4c9f-5584-04b0

2019-03-27T11:26:48.954+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container

2019-03-27T11:26:49.085+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR bash: S/4HANA: No such file or directory

2019-03-27T11:26:49.095+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 127

2019-03-27T11:26:49.241+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell dcee36cd-b198-4815-bc83-659c0ff008fd stopping instance 54cb5da2-e6be-4c9f-5584-04b0

2019-03-27T11:26:49.241+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell dcee36cd-b198-4815-bc83-659c0ff008fd destroying container for instance 54cb5da2-e6be-4c9f-5584-04b0

2019-03-27T11:26:49.297+0000 [API/14] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"

2019-03-27T11:26:49.308+0000 [API/14] OUT App instance exited with guid b07d82eb-c0a9-4778-97a3-0027cb123871 payload: {"instance"=>"54cb5da2-e6be-4c9f-5584-04b0", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"dcee36cd-b198-4815-bc83-659c0ff008fd", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 127", "crash_count"=>3, "crash_timestamp"=>1553686009236498655, "version"=>"ce5d1861-170d-4eb6-a3b9-02738dea412f"}

2019-03-27T11:26:49.804+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell dcee36cd-b198-4815-bc83-659c0ff008fd successfully destroyed container for instance 54cb5da2-e6be-4c9f-5584-04b0

2019-03-27T11:27:32.185+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell a6b77746-e396-440d-84bb-041074ae56fa creating container for instance 9c622d48-b55e-4976-55d0-6926

2019-03-27T11:27:32.802+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell a6b77746-e396-440d-84bb-041074ae56fa successfully created container for instance 9c622d48-b55e-4976-55d0-6926

2019-03-27T11:27:36.588+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container

2019-03-27T11:27:36.703+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR bash: S/4HANA: No such file or directory

2019-03-27T11:27:36.717+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 127


2019-03-27T11:27:36.921+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell a6b77746-e396-440d-84bb-041074ae56fa stopping instance 9c622d48-b55e-4976-55d0-6926

2019-03-27T11:27:36.922+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell a6b77746-e396-440d-84bb-041074ae56fa destroying container for instance 9c622d48-b55e-4976-55d0-6926

2019-03-27T11:27:36.976+0000 [API/24] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"

2019-03-27T11:27:37.191+0000 [API/24] OUT App instance exited with guid b07d82eb-c0a9-4778-97a3-0027cb123871 payload: {"instance"=>"9c622d48-b55e-4976-55d0-6926", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"a6b77746-e396-440d-84bb-041074ae56fa", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 127", "crash_count"=>4, "crash_timestamp"=>1553686056917496012, "version"=>"ce5d1861-170d-4eb6-a3b9-02738dea412f"}

2019-03-27T11:27:37.516+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell a6b77746-e396-440d-84bb-041074ae56fa successfully destroyed container for instance 9c622d48-b55e-4976-55d0-6926
```

Comment: If Sander's answer has helped you fix the issue, please mark his answer as 'accepted' by clicking on the green checkmark. Otherwise, please provide further information on the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check which path your project is in. It seems there is an issue with the slash in the `S/4HANA` String in a file path: `ERR bash: S/4HANA: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Hi Sander,
Thanks for the reply!
But there is no folder named S/4HANA in the project or where the file resides.
The project location is : C:\Users\*******\Documents\SDK\Projects\address-manager.
Why is compiler trying for the folder S/4HANA?

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: Could you share a minimal non-working example? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sander,
Please find the gitlink for application.
https://github.com/rahulrajeevratnamsapcom/address-manager

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: @RahulRajeev Thanks, will have a look.

Comment: Could you please post the command line output of the `mvn tomee:run` command?

Comment: @RahulRajeev I cannot reproduce the issue. When checking out the project, building it and then running `mvn tomee:run` in the application folder, the app starts normally. Do you have more details on the error as Dennis mentioned?

Comment: hi , please find the google doc for log. 
 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SVdwKyCy_Gt0bGfnkaFaDsf3mDmcmnCuXsu0xOpjQkc/edit?usp=sharing_eip&ts=5cc2c415

Comment: @RahulRajeev See my second answer, the port 8005 that TomEE uses as shutdown port is already in use.

Comment: @RahulRajeev If you solved your question or if this comment/answer solved your question, please mark it as accepted or consider providing your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace contains an error that the shutdown port 8005 of TomEE is already in use. Please configure the TomEE Maven Plugin to use another port or stop the process running on that port.

More details at http://tomee.apache.org/maven/run-mojo.html#tomeeShutdownPort